# ListBoxItems: How to individualize item rendering, depending on item content

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, listbox

I want to individualize the kind, how the fields of a class shall be visualized in a ListBox item.

1) I tried various way using XAML. Eg I had various panels in my DataTemplate and used a ValueConverter to determine which panel to use and hide the others. But is was quite confusing, difficult and very limited when it came to layout  and formatting variations.

2) Then I found a second approach: I created an AttachedProperty for the class I wanted to display in the ItemPanel. In the DataTemplate I attached my new AttachedProperty that represents my class und use the MetaData function PropertyChangedCallback of the AttachedProperty. Let's say, I place a Border as the only control in my DataTemplate. The PropertyChangedCallback gets that Border and the class object. Now I can custom create the content of the border (replace its Child property) depending on the values of my item object.

Version 2 is working quite good. Whenever adding an item to the ListBox or updating an item's properties the ValueChangedCallback gives me the chance to adjust the appearance.

But how can I change the content of the border (in my DataTemplate), depending on the selection state or mouse over state?

Important for me is, that I can build the content of my ItemPanel with C# and not with XAML, so that there are no limits when it comes to layouting and formatting.

Comment: I'm curious, why would there be limits when using XAML? My first suggestion would have been to use a DataTemplateSelector to select a DataTemplate for each case, or if you want a template per type simply bind DataTemplates to each type and let them be used implicitly.

Comment: DataTemplateSelector is too static. Assume you want to display a string in an item. And you have a textbox where you type "abc", and how could you highlight all occurrences of "abc" in the displayed string of the item? Using the PropertyChangedCallback I can split the string, build a TextBlock out of different formatted Runs and place it the Border (Child property). How do you do that with XAML? And it can get even more complex. - What I need is a dynamic DataTemplate that can be created in C#. And I need the item, the selection/mouse over state and access to other controls.

Comment: There are ways to intervene with your own code in XAML, so I don't mean to religiously use XAML and nothing else. All I'm saying is there are built in things that can help. Templates can contain custom controls or behaviors or any number of things that can modify how things work, and it's often easier to work with the frameworks you're using rather than against them. I don't have all the info so I'm not saying I know your situation and can dictate what's best, just that...

Comment: templates and template selectors always worked fine for me, whereas building templates in code is a lot more tedious and less maintainable.

Comment: @AlexPaven : _**...it's often easier to work with the frameworks you're using rather than against them.**_ nailed it...:O)